# PowerShell object representation

Tags: powershell, object, representation

There are different ways to represent (display) an object in PowerShell but when it comes to complex objects it is either very verbose or quiet useless:

```
$Object = @{ 'a' = 1; 'b' = 2 }
```

Just outputting (`Format-Host`, or `Format-List`) returns a multiline output, as:

```
$Object

Name                           Value
----                           -----
a                              1
b                              2
```

Converting it to a string `"$Object"` or `$Object.ToString()` doesn't reveal anything about its contents:

```
System.Collections.Hashtable
```

Converting it to Json `$Object |ConvertTo-Json -Compress`, gets close to what I would like to see (but a little too expressive cmdlet for what I need):

```
{"a":1,"b":2}
```

I wonder whether there is a way access the representation formatting used by PowerShell display cmdlets, as e.g. the value behind the `ImmediateBaseObject` and `BaseObject`:

```
$Object.PSObject

Members             : {System.Object Item(System.Object key) {get;set;}, bool IsReadOnly {get;}, bool IsFixedSize {get;}, bool IsSynchronized {get;}…}
Properties          : {bool IsReadOnly {get;}, bool IsFixedSize {get;}, bool IsSynchronized {get;}, System.Collections.ICollection Keys {get;}…}
Methods             : {Add, Clear, Clone, Contains…}
ImmediateBaseObject : {[a, 1], [b, 2]}                     # <-- This representation
BaseObject          : {[a, 1], [b, 2]}                     #
TypeNames           : {System.Collections.Hashtable, System.Object}
```

Wishful thinking, I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
[PowerShellFormat]$Object
```

And get the same formatting back for any (complex) object as shown behind `BaseObject` for `$Object.PSObject`.
As for this case:

```
{[a, 1], [b, 2]}
```

Comment: "And get the same formatting back for any (complex) object as shown behind `BaseObject` for `$Object.PSObject`" only IDictionary are displayed as you're showing, other types would display their Fully Qualified Name or not display anything at all as is the case for `pscustomobject`

Comment: Maybe the following (irreversible) dirty trick? `"{$($Object.GetEnumerator())}"` returns `{[a, 1] [b, 2]}`…

Comment: @Santiago, value types (string, int, datetime) work (just the usual way of formatting), arrays work, other dictionaries (e.g. `[Collections.Generic.Dictionary[string, object]]` ) work. But indeed, it only shows one level and `[PSCustomObjects]` don't shows any results at all.

Comment: You can create a simple function that returns `$Object.PSObject | Format-Table ImmediateBaseObject -HideTableHeaders` but my guess is that its as closer as it gets to what you want

Comment: @JozefZ, that looks very promising. Can you put that as an formal answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JosefZ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3439404/josefz) has provided the crucial pointer:

- Call `.GetEnumerator()` on your **dictionary** in order to enumerate its *entries*, which are key-value pairs, such as of type [`[System.Collections.DictionaryEntry]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.DictionaryEntry) in [`hashtable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.Hashtable) instances.
- Unlike dictionaries *as a whole*, their *entries* stringify meaningfully, in the form `[<key>, <value>]` - though it's important to note that this is just a *for-display* representation, not suitable for *programmatic* processing.
- When PowerShell's formatting system stringifies a dictionary stored in a *property* of an input object, it treats it as an *array of entries*, and stringifies that array *similarly* to how arrays are stringified in *expandable* strings:

  - The difference is that the whole representation is enclosed in `{...}` and that the (stringified) elements are separated with `,` . You saw this in the display formatting of `@{ 'a' = 1; 'b' = 2 }.psobject` (`.ImmediateBaseObject` and `.BaseObject` properties).
  - I'm not aware of a public method that would produce this format, but it isn't hard to produce it yourself:

```
# -> '{[a, 1], [b, 2]}'
'{' + (@( @{ 'a' = 1; 'b' = 2 }.GetEnumerator() ) -join ', ') + '}'
```

Note:

- The `.GetEnumerator()` call must be wrapped in `@(...)` to force actual enumeration, resulting in an *array*.
- It follows that you can use the above for *arrays* as inputs too.

---

Getting an analogous string representation or **`[pscustomobject]`** instances is much simpler: Use *string interpolation*, i.e. embed the object in an [expandable (double-quoted) string (`"..."`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings):

```
$obj = [pscustomobject] @{ 'a' = 1; 'b' = 2 }
"$obj" # -> '@{a=1; b=2}'
```

Note:

- Unlike hashtables/dictionaries, `[pscsutomobject]` instances stringify *the same way* in expandable strings and as properties of formatted object representations.
- Note the difference in formats compared to the hashtable visualization, with the property name-value pairs separate with `=` (and no whitespace), multiple properties separated with `;`, and `@{` as the opening delimiter.
  Curiously, this format is very similar to the syntax of a *hashtable* literal.

---

Finally, just to demonstrate that PowerShell's formatting system indeed produces the representations above for hashtables and `[pscustomobject]` instances used *as properties*:

```
@{ 
  hashtable = @{ 'a' = 1; 'b' = 2 }
  pscustomobject = [pscustomobject] @{ 'a' = 1; 'b' = 2 }
}
```

Output:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
pscustomobject                 @{a=1; b=2}
hashtable                      {[a, 1], [b, 2]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$object = @{'a'=1; 'b'=2}
$x = [pscustomobject]$object

'Members'
$x | gm
'  '
'Content'
$x
'  '
'Properties'
$x.a
$x.b
'   '
'CSV format'
$x | ConvertTo-csv
'   '
'Json format'
$x | ConvertTo-Json
```

This will convert a and b into Noteproperty names, with the corresponding values.